# Idiomatic no-op/"pass"

Tags: clojure

What's the (most) idiomatic Clojure representation of `no-op`? I.e.,

```
(def r (ref {}))
...
(let [der @r]
    (match [(:a der) (:b der)]
        [nil nil] (do (fill-in-a) (fill-in-b))
        [_ nil] (fill-in-b)
        [nil _] (fill-in-a)
        [_ _] ????))
```

Python has `pass`. What should I be using in Clojure?

ETA: I ask mostly because I've run into places (`cond`, e.g.) where not supplying anything causes an error. I realize that "most" of the time, an equivalent of `pass` isn't needed, but when it is, I'd like to know what's the most Clojuric.

Comment: Thinking in terms of noops feels pretty procedural; if you weren't relying on side-effects, the question wouldn't have come up. I'd argue that code where one needs to ask this question is less than idiomatic already. :)

Comment: not sure what the above code does business wise, but according to what is written, `:both-filled`, `:not-null`, `:default`, `:whatever-makes-sense` ? also do destructuring in let: `(let [{:keys [a b]} @r] (match [a b] ...))`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy What if you're forced to use an api with callbacks and you want nothing to happen on callback, but you're not allowed to supply it with nil.

Comment: @Jeb, if you can't leave the callback out (ie. passing `{:callback-i-want (fn ...)}` and leaving out `:callback-i-dont-want` entirely), the API is unidiomatic. I'm not saying you never have to do unidiomatic things; I'm just saying that when you're in this situation, you're in one of those places.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see the keyword `:default` used in cases like this fairly commonly.
It has the nice property of being recognizable in the output and or logs. This way when you see a log line like: "process completed :default" it's obvious that nothing actually ran. This takes advantage of the fact that **keywords are truthy** in Clojure so the default will be counted as a success.

Answer (score 9):

There are no "statements" in Clojure, but there are an infinite number of ways to "do nothing". An empty do block `(do)`, literally indicates that one is "doing nothing" and evaluates to nil. Also, I agree with the comment that the question itself indicates that you are not using Clojure in an idiomatic way, regardless of this specific stylistic question.

Answer (score 6):

The most analogous thing that I can think of in Clojure to a "statement that does nothing" from imperative programming would be a *function* that does nothing. There are a couple of built-ins that can help you here: `identity` is a single-arg function that simply returns its argument, and `constantly` is a higher-order function that accepts a value, and returns a function that will accept any number of arguments and return that value. Both are useful as placeholders in situations where you need to pass a function but don't want that function to actually do much of anything. A simple example:

```
(defn twizzle [x]
  (let [f (cond (even? x) (partial * 4)
                (= 0 (rem x 3)) (partial + 2)
                :else identity)]
    (f (inc x))))
```

Rewriting this function to "do nothing" in the default case, while possible, would require an awkward rewrite without the use of `identity`.